# Missing `parse` information inside vignette build

Tags: r, parsing, knitr

## Goal

The goal is to create a package that parses R scripts and lists functions (from the package - like `mvbutils`- but also imports).

## Function

The main function relies on parsing R script with
`d<-getParseData(x = parse(text = deparse(x)))`

## Reproducible code

For example in an interactive R session the output of

```
 x<-test<-function(x){x+1}
 d<-getParseData(x = parse(text = deparse(x)))
```

Has for first few lines:

```
   line1 col1 line2 col2 id parent          token terminal     text
23     1    1     4    1 23      0           expr    FALSE         
1      1    1     1    8  1     23       FUNCTION     TRUE function
2      1   10     1   10  2     23            '('     TRUE        (
3      1   11     1   11  3     23 SYMBOL_FORMALS     TRUE        x
4      1   12     1   12  4     23            ')'     TRUE        )
```

## Error

When building a vignette with `knitr` containing - either with knit html from RStudio or `devtools::build_vignettes`, the output of the previous chunk of code is `NULL`. On the other hand using "knitr::knit" inside an R session will give the correct output.

## Questions:

Is there a reason for the parser to behave differently inside the `knit` function/environment, and is there a way to bypass this?

### Update

Changing code to:

```
x<-test<-function(x){x+1}
d<-getParseData(x = parse(text = deparse(x),keep.source = TRUE))
```

Fixes the issue, but this does not answer the question of why the same function behaves differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help page `?options`:

> keep.source:
>
> When `TRUE`, the source code for functions (newly defined or loaded) is stored internally allowing comments to be kept in the right places. Retrieve the source by printing or using `deparse(fn, control = "useSource")`.
>
> The default is `interactive()`, i.e., `TRUE` for interactive use.

When building the vignette, you are running a non-interactive R session, so the source code is discarded in `parse()`.

```
parse(file = "", n = NULL, text = NULL, prompt = "?",
      keep.source = getOption("keep.source"), srcfile,
      encoding = "unknown")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought there should be something like this but it is always strange to have functions that behave differently.